# Chart.js: Force show the last tick with autoSkip:true

Tags: javascript, chart.js

On my Chart.js element, I have ticks with time string on x-axis.

```
scales: {
  x: {
    type: 'time',
    time: {
      distribution: 'series',
      tooltipFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
      displayFormats: {
        millisecond: 'HH:mm:ss',
        second: 'HH:mm:ss',
        minute: 'HH:mm:ss',
        hour: 'HH:mm:ss',
      },
},
```

My problem is the last tick is skipped sometimes.
I tried to set `includeBounds: true`, but it didn't work.

Is there any option or work-around to show the last tick always?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @E.Maggini, I've updated question as you suggested.